# XDMCP locally using Unix sockets

Tags: debian, socket, lightdm, xephyr, xdmcp

Is there any way to start a **XDMCP** session, say with **Xephyr** in **LightDM**, locally through **Unix Sockets** instead of **IP**?

For performance I was wondering if, somehow, I can avoid any network stack working with **Xephyr** and the **XDMCP** server in the same machine.

Comment: Do you mean unix sockets? Because communication with IP addresses also uses sockets. Anyway you'd better explain your actual problem in details to avoid https://xyproblem.info/ .

Comment: You're right @A.B I mean Unix Sockets, I'll edit the question.